# Compiling HTML in growl alert

Tags: angularjs, jgrowl

I am trying to get HTML to compile in a growl alert.  Here is my code:

```
var html = '<h3>' + rejection.config.method + ' '+ rejection.config.url + '</h3>' +
   '<hr><div>' +
   (_.isObject(rejection.data) ? ('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(rejection.data, null, 2) + '</pre>') : rejection.data) +
   '</div>' + '<a ng-click="reportError($event)"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn hoverable"></i>  Report this error</a>';
   growl.addErrorMessage(html,
   {
       enableHtml: true
   });
   $compile(html)($scope);
```

On the page the HTML looks like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="message.text" ng-switch-when="true" class="ng-scope ng-binding"><h3>GET services/link</h3><hr><div>null</div><a><i class="fa fa-bullhorn hoverable"></i>  Report this error</a></div>
```

The html should have the directive that I appended: `"<a ng-click="reportError($event)"` and it is not being added. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I just updated it hopefully to be more descriptive.  I am trying to add a ng-click directive in the html i am putting in the growl alert.  However nothing is being appended, so I tried to $compile it but that doesn't seem to work either.  Not sure what to do at this point